# HTML5 событие изменения субтитров

Tags: html5, видео

Как получить событие изменения субтитров тега  с возможностью получить текст текущего субтитра?

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: для возможности получить перевод конкретного слова из субтитров

Answer (score 1):

За субтитры в HTML5 отвечает стандарт WebVTT, вот его спецификация: http://dev.w3.org/html5/webvtt/

Могут пригодиться готовые библиотеки для парсинга WebVTT файлов - "webvtt parser" в Google.

Сам не проверял, но думаю, что событие можно отловить просто установив `onchange` на тег `<track>`, т.к. это полноправный HTML тег.

Вот еще [статья из MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Video_Text_Tracks_Format) на тему.